# Implement Facebook autologin

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am integrating facebook connect in my website...currently i am able to authenticate user's and fetch his/her basic details but what i need to do is implement the auto login that is the user once logs in by entering his credentials ...next time onwards whenever he/she visits my website the user should be automatically logged in and his basic details should be displayed without the need of clicking the login button once again...any advice/suggestions/guidance would be of great help....Thank you in advance

Here is What My Code is Right now...

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title>Facebook login</title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <table style="width: 30%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td  style="color: #33ccff; font-size: large; font-weight: bold; text-transform:  capitalize;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  style="margin-top: 350px; align-content:center">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        // Load the SDK Asynchronously 
                        (function (d) {
                            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
                        }(document));

                        // Init the SDK upon load
                        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                            FB.init({
                                appId: 'xxxxxxxxx', // App ID 
                                channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File 
                                status: true, // check login status 
                                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session 
                                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML 
                            });

                            // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events 
                            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {

                                if (response.authResponse) {

                                    // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook 
                                    FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                                        if (me.name) {
                                            document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                                            document.getElementById('UserEmail').innerHTML = me.email;
                                            document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = me.location;
                                            //document.getElementById('AccessToken').innerHTML = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                                            //getPhoto();

                                        }
                                    })
                                    document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                                    document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
                                } else {
                                    // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook 
                                    document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
                                    document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
                                }
                            });


                            $("#auth-logoutlink").click(function () { FB.logout(function () { window.location.reload(); }); });


                            function getPhoto() {
                                FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function (response) {

                                    var str = "<br/> <img src='" + response.data.url + "' style=height:60px; width:40px;/>";

                                    document.getElementById("ProfilePic").innerHTML = str;

                                });



                            }



                        }

                    </script>


                    <div id="auth-status">
                        <div id="auth-loggedout">
                            <div autologoutlink="true" class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_checkins,read_mailbox,read_stream">
                                Login with Facebook
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none;">
                            <img src="../img/fb_icon_325x325.png" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;" />
                            Hi, <span id="auth-displayname"></span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<b>Friends(</b><span id="userFriends"></span><b>)</b>
                            <div id="ProfilePic">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <b>Email :</b><span id="UserEmail"></span><br />
                                 <b>location :</b><span id="location"></span><br />

                            </div>
                            <div id="AccessToken1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="margin-top: 350px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User FB.getLoginStatus: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

It checks for authorization and refreshes the User Token without a page refresh. Just use it right after FB.init instead of FB.Event.subscribe, see code in the docs.

Comment: Hi, thanks luschn for the response...but the above solution you have mentioned works fine only till the browser is not closed,but once the browser is closed it again asks for login that is user session stays connected till the browser we have run to login, is not closed

Comment: what do you mean with "login"? if you log out of facebook, of course you have to login again.

Comment: no i am not signing out of facebook... if i just close the browser without signing out and again open the browser and run my application in my localhost it shows my login status as not connected

Comment: can you post a test link?

Comment: I tried posting my code at jsfiddle but it is not working......the link is here.....http://jsfiddle.net/8dpmj3he/

Comment: "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration" - it will not work on jsfiddle, do you have a real test link? the code with getLoginStatus looks good btw, that is how i meant it.

Comment: hey luschn if you don't mind can i have your facebook id ...as extended discussions are not allowed here....so you can help me out over facebook chat.